# Get image dimension from canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas sketchpad of 612x300px. If I paint something into it and get the image with `toDataURL()` I get an image of 612x300px, but I only want the part that is painted without the background. I have no idea how can I start with this...

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: The `toDataURL` method always returns data for the whole image. If you want only a part of the image, then you will have to create a new canvas element of that size and copy the image data into it at the right position.

Comment: Yes, but I haven't the dimensions of the paint. For example, if I paint a circle with the mouse, I need to get only the circle on a new image... Maybe by removing the white background? I can use server or client side.

Comment: If you “paint with the mouse”, then you should be able to capture the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Edited to reflect new information]**

Here is how to extract the portion of a picture that the user has sketched upon.

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/TPHrv/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory;}
    #container{position:relative; margin:15px;}
    canvas{border:1px solid red; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
    #sketch{position:absolute; top:315px; left:0px;}
    #results{border:1px solid green; position:absolute; top:350px; left:0px;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var background=document.getElementById("background");
    var bkCtx=background.getContext("2d");
    var lastX;
    var lastY;
    var strokeColor="red";
    var strokeWidth=2;
    var canMouseX;
    var canMouseY;
    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var isMouseDown=false;
    var top=10000;
    var left=10000;
    var right=0;
    var bottom=0;

    // draw the background
    var count=0;
    var radius=15;
    var d=radius*2
    bkCtx.strokeStyle="orange";
    bkCtx.lineWidth=1;
    bkCtx.fillStyle="blue";
    for(var y=0;y<10;y++){
      for(var x=0;x<10;x++){
          count++;
          bkCtx.beginPath();
          bkCtx.rect(x*30,y*30,30,30);
          //bkCtx.arc(x+radius, y+radius, radius, 0 , 2 * Math.PI, false);
          bkCtx.fillText(count,x*30+9,y*30+15);
          bkCtx.stroke();
          console.log(y);
        }
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      lastX=canMouseX;
      lastY=canMouseY;
      isMouseDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseup stuff here
      isMouseDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseOut stuff here
      isMouseDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousemove stuff here
      if(isMouseDown){
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY);
          ctx.lineTo(canMouseX,canMouseY);
          ctx.stroke();     
          lastX=canMouseX;
          lastY=canMouseY;
          // define the bounding box of all drawings
          if(canMouseX<left){left=canMouseX;}
          if(canMouseX>right){right=canMouseX;}
          if(canMouseY<top){top=canMouseY;}
          if(canMouseY>bottom){bottom=canMouseY;}

      }
    }

    function capture(e){
        var imageData=bkCtx.getImageData(left,top,right-left,bottom-top);
        var temp=document.createElement("canvas");
        var tempCtx=temp.getContext("2d");
        temp.width=right-left;
        temp.height=bottom-top;
        tempCtx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
        var results=document.getElementById("results");
        results.src=temp.toDataURL();
        console.log(left+"/"+top+" -- "+right+"/"+bottom);
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});
    $("#sketch").click(function(e){capture(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <p>Drag to select an area to extract</p>
  <div id="container">
    <canvas id="background" width=300 height=300></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
    <button id="sketch">Extract the sketch area</button>
    <img id="results">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[This was the original answer – it needed to be updated after more information was offered]**

You are on the right track…

Now, just place your background on a **separate** image or canvas *behind* your sketching canvas.

The user will see the background and yet draw on the sketch canvas above.

Since your sketching canvas remains uncluttered with the background bits, when you want to capture it with .toDataURL() you get pure sketch bits!

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/JSux2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
    #wrapper{left-margin:150px;}
    #results{border:1px solid green; position:absolute; top:0; left:300px;}
    button{position:absolute; top:275px; left:0;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var lastX;
    var lastY;
    var strokeColor="red";
    var strokeWidth=2;
    var canMouseX;
    var canMouseY;
    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var isMouseDown=false;

    // load the background image and set the canvas to the same size
    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){

        var background=document.getElementById("background");
        var bkCtx=background.getContext("2d");
        background.width=img.width;
        background.height=img.height;
        bkCtx.drawImage(img,0,0);

        canvas.width=img.width;
        canvas.height=img.height;

        var results=document.getElementById("results");
        results.width=img.width;
        results.height=img.height;
        console.log(img);
    }
    img.src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house-icon.png";

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      $("#downlog").html("Down: "+ canMouseX + " / " + canMouseY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      lastX=canMouseX;
      lastY=canMouseY;
      isMouseDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      $("#uplog").html("Up: "+ canMouseX + " / " + canMouseY);

      // Put your mouseup stuff here
      isMouseDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      $("#outlog").html("Out: "+ canMouseX + " / " + canMouseY);

      // Put your mouseOut stuff here
      isMouseDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      $("#movelog").html("Move: "+ canMouseX + " / " + canMouseY);

      // Put your mousemove stuff here
      if(isMouseDown){
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY);
          ctx.lineTo(canMouseX,canMouseY);
          ctx.stroke();     
          lastX=canMouseX;
          lastY=canMouseY;
      }
    }

    function extract(){
        var results=document.getElementById("results");
        results.src=canvas.toDataURL();
        alert("ok");
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});
    $("#sketch").click(function(e){extract(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="background" width=100 height=100></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100></canvas>
    <button id="sketch">Extract the sketch</button>
    <img id="results" width=10 height=10>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think I don't explain well. I need to remove the background and crop the paint, not get the whole canvas. So if I have the 612x300 canvas and paint a 1x10px horizontal line on any place of the canvas, I need to get a 1x10px image, not a 612x300.

Comment: OK, I understand now.  A question: If you draw two lines in an X, do you want the square that contains the X or do you want just the 2 lines of the X?